# Can I change the look of the panel icons in XFCE?

Tags: panel, xfce

I'd like to make the notification and workspaces symbols (all in the so-called *Panel 1*) a bit brighter. Or change them to whatever makes them a bit more distinguishable.

Currently, it looks like this:

[image]

This is the *elementary XFCE* style for the icons. Ironically, the *Elementary XFCE dark* theme is a bit better, but still, the bluetooth and Dropbox icons are pretty dark. It's not easy on the eyes, IMHO. Same goes for the workspaces switcher. The workspaces are only distinguishable because I know where they are and there is a single blue mark on the active one.

Would anyone happen to have any sort of advice on how to improve this issue from *my* perspective? (I am asking this specific way since I imagine some of you are fine with it.)

Comment: Have you played with the panel background color? Or tried a different icon set?

Comment: I did, that was helpful device, thanks. However, since I have Synapse running the whole time (have it mapped to Super + F too) it usually stays blank with different icon sets. :/

Comment: @vasa1 Although nearly one year old, your comment still stands. Please do submit your comment as an answer, maybe phrased slightly different, so I can mark it as solved. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common problem when users change away from default settings is that something unintended could happen. In this particular instance, a change in the icon theme leads to poor contrast of *some* icons with the background of the panel.

The simplest option is to modify the panel background color to the extent required.

Or, if one is by and large happy with the icon theme and panel background, and also has other icon  themes available, a little searching in other icon themes may help find a replacement for the troublesome icon. Another option, depending on one's skills, is to modify the appearance of the truant icon using a graphics program or, if the icon is an svg file, one could even change colors using a text editor.